# How to sanitize data in php in order to avoid SQL injection?

Tags: php, security, sql-injection

I already used the PDO:

```
        $stmt = $aPDO->prepare("INSERT INTO ".$this->getM_oUser()->getM_sTableName()." (email, hash_pw, hash_key) VALUES (:email, :hash_pw, :hash_key)");                                             
        $stmt->bindValue(':email', $this->getM_oUser()->getM_sEmail());
        $stmt->bindValue(':hash_pw', $this->getM_oUser()->getM_sHash_pw());
        $stmt->bindValue(':hash_key', $this->getM_oUser()->getM_sHash_Key());

        $stmt->execute();
```

Should I also use mysql_real_escape_string() to handle the user input string? Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Are PDO prepared statements sufficient to prevent SQL injection?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/134099/are-pdo-prepared-statements-sufficient-to-prevent-sql-injection)

Answer (score 1):

Using prepared statements with bound parameters is enough. You don't need to use `mysql_real_escape_string` (and you probably could not even if you wanted -- you 'd need a MySql connection resource in hand to do it).

Answer (score 0):

I'd do something like that to exclude a lot of useless characters from your table name:

```
$tableName = '`' . preg_replace('`[^-a-zA-Z0-9_]`', $this->getM_oUser()->getM_sTableName()).'`';
$stmt = $aPDO->prepare("INSERT INTO ".$tableName." (email, hash_pw, hash_key) VALUES (:email, :hash_pw, :hash_key)");
```